# 90° Rotated images

Tags: graphics

I don't understand why image n.2 3 and 4 are 90° rotated in the anti-clockwise direction when I run my code.

The images are .jpg

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[eulermath]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.2in, right=1in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\usepackage[eulermath]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{subfig}
\graphicspath{{Immagini/}}
\begin{document}
     \begin{figure} [h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Immagini/glass drill}
        \caption{Drilling process on glass fiber composite.}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure} [h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Immagini/glass trim}
        \caption{Trimming process on glass fiber composite.}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure} [h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Immagini/carbon trim}
        \caption{Trimming process on carbon fiber composite.}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure} [h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Immagini/machine}
        \caption{Trimming process of carbon fiber seen from the a wide angle.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvny8.png
the image is picture 3 and 4

Comment: Sometimes the metadata in the image file is weird. Sorry, I do not have a better answer. Try to open the images in an image editor and rotate the image(and then save the image).

Comment: Not completely. I mean I checked with that software the orientation of my image and it results rotated on the right side. I switched off the option he suggested but nothing happened apparently.

Comment: Then rotate the picture outside of Latex to the other direction and see if that workaround solves your problem.

Comment: I'm trying to use [angle=-90] like:
\begin{figure} [h]
 \centering
 \subfloat[]
 {\includegraphics[scale=0.07]{Immagini/glass drill}} \quad
 \subfloat[]
 {\includegraphics[scale=0.07][angle=-90]{Immagini/glass trim}} \quad
 \caption{(a) drilling process on glass fiber composite, (b) Trimming process on glass fiber.}
\end{figure}

but I got an error Argument of \Gin@iii has an extra }. ...le=0.07][angle=-90]{Immagini/glass trim}}

Comment: How can I rotate the picture outside of Latex sorry?

Comment: Using one of many freeware to manipulate images.

Comment: It doesn't work. When I rotate it by 90° in the clockwise direction and put into latex it processes it as a 180° turn

Comment: I have to do it twice first -90 and then +90 for latex to process it as 0° image

Comment: Surely not an ideal solution but the best I can think of at this point is time.

Comment: Ok apparently it was sufficient to do rotate on IrfanView

Comment: Should I write a short answer so that your question can be finished?

Comment: Like you prefer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open the image in an [image manipulation software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_raster_graphics_editors) and manually
  rotate it in the opposite direction.
- *Remark: Typically, your OS has a built-in image software (the default image viewer) that is able to do that.*
- Save the image and then try
  again to include it in your LaTeX document.